# Use TeamCity permissions to limit user access to specific build parameters

Tags: teamcity

I am using TeamCity 10 and have a build configuration that uses a number of build parameters.  Of these parameters a subset are prompted for when triggering a build and are required.

I am attempting to create a new role in TeamCity with VERY limited permissions that will only allow the user to view specific projects and trigger builds.  In order for this user to be able to specify the required parameters I have to give them the TC 'Customize Build Parameters' permission.  Unfortunately this also gives them the ability to change ALL build parameters and can lead to problems/confusion.  Is there anyway to choose the specific build parameters the user is able to change instead of them gaining access to all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create parameters that the low privilege users could not edit/view by configuring the parameters to be "read only" or "hidden".  The parameters I wanted the users to be able to change are configured as regular parameters which can be edited from the Run Build modal.